# Как использавать PhotoImage как часть текста

Tags: python, tkinter, photoimage

Делаю игру, в которой будут объявления, где упоминаются ресурсы. Я хочу, чтобы в этих объявлениях название ресурса заменялось на картинку, которую я сам нарисовал. Вот пример:

> Слишком мало . Можно получить, перерабатывая  на фабрике.

Конечно это можно нарисовать с помощью `tkinter.Label` вот так:

```
import tkinter  
tk = tkinter.Tk()
images = [tkinter.PhotoImage(master = tk, image = 'Нитки.gif'),
          tkinter.PhotoImage(master = tk, image = 'Шерсть.gif')]
message = [tkinter.Label(master = tk, text = 'Слишком мало '),
          tkinter.Label(master = tk, image = images[0],
          tkinter.Label(master = tk, text = '. Можно получить переробатовая '),
          tkinter.Label(master = tk, image = images[1]),
          tkinter.Label(master = tk, text = ' на фабрике.')]

for step in mesaege:
      step.pack(side = 'left')

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Но если нужно такой текст вставить в `tkinter.Button` таким способом не получится. К тому же он жутко неудобный. Можете пожалуйста предложить способ получше?

Comment: Вставьте изображение в текстовый виджет. Как-то так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75232960/i-have-managed-to-insert-an-image-into-a-tkinter-text-widget-but-how-to-make-it